# Why doesn't 'Tidy' in Broom work as intended for an epi.2by2 object?

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom

I am using the package epiR to calculate measures of association (rate ratio and attributable risk). Results are outputted to a list. I want to get these estimates into one overall dataframe - I thought Broom could do this - see [here](https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/tidy.epi.2by2.html#see-also).

This is what I have attached:

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_3.0.1    ggplot2_3.1.1  
 [8] tidyverse_1.2.1 dplyr_0.8.1     broom_0.5.6    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.4     compiler_3.5.3   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.5.3      jsonlite_1.6    
 [8] lubridate_1.7.4  lifecycle_0.2.0  nlme_3.1-137     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.4.5     
[15] Matrix_1.2-17    cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10  haven_2.1.0      withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.4.0      
[22] generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.2.4      hms_0.4.2        grid_3.5.3       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0        
[29] readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.4  scales_1.0.0     ellipsis_0.3.0   rvest_0.3.4     
[36] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4    
>
```

This is the code I have run:

```
tabh7 <- table(ispa.h7$mat2,ispa.h7$cov,ispa.h7$Sex)
rh7 <- epi.2by2(dat = tabh7, method = "cohort.count", 
                 conf.level = 0.95, units = 100, outcome = "as.columns")

tidy(rh7, parameters = "moa")
```

And this is the message:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class epi.2by2
```

I have tried deleting my .RHistory. I never save my workspaces. What could be the problem?

Comment: That change is not available on the CRAN version of the broom package `0.5.6`. That change is currently in the development version that's available on github. This is listed [in the latest release notes](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/blob/4f7aa8adae16b813db494a25a26b241dd187804f/NEWS.md). You can install the dev version if you like with `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/broom")` Or wait till version 0.7 is released to CRAN (no idea when that will be though).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know that I want to venture into devtools...